# Send Grid - When I send an email using the api, the email I receive is missing all the design e.g. just shows the text

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid

**Send Grid - When I send an email using the api, the email I receive is missing all the design e.g. just shows the text.**

I'm using node js app with javascript.

I have it all working with the api.

I just need the template its calling to include the images.

Is there some sort of send grid setting?

This is the transactional emails im using. I call the ID like in the code sample below.

It calls the template fine and just doesnt include the images and only the text.

**Example from docs:**

```
var email = new sendgrid.Email();
email.addTo('example@domain.com');
email.subject = "Send with templates app";
email.from = 'from@example.com';
email.text = 'Hi there!';
email.html = '<h1>Hi there!</h1>';

// add filter settings one at a time
email.addFilter('templates', 'enable', 1);
email.addFilter('templates', 'template_id', '09c6ab89-9157-4710-8ca4-db7927c631d6');
```

Link to the docs: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the email.text and see if that fixes it.

Comment: If that does "fix" it. Try and see if setting email.text AFTER setting email.html makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I swapped email.text for email.html and that seemed to work.

It must of needed some html markup for it to work